# Derivative of ln x

Tags: calculus

Prove that the derivative of $\ln x$ is $\frac1x$  for $x≠0$

Proof :

Suppose $x>0$  and write $f(x)=ln⁡〖 x〗$  in the equivalent from
$x=e^{f(x)}$

Differentiating both sides of the equation with respect to x,

$1=e^{f(x)}   .f' (x)$

$f' (x)=1/e^{f(x)}$

$f' (x)=1/x$

How about if $x<0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x<0$, we might want to find the derivative of $\ln | x|.$  You could mimic what you did for positive $x$, or just use the chain rule:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\ln|x| = \frac{d}{dx} \ln(-x) =
\frac{1}{-x}(-1) = \frac{1}{x}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $\ln x$ is defined for $x>0$ or that, equivalently the range of $e^{x}$ is $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know complex numbers? If you do, you can use the following reasoning:
\begin{equation} z=re^{i\theta} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} \Rightarrow log(z)=log(r)+i\theta. \end{equation}
So, now when we are working on negative real axis, $\theta=\pi$ and $z=Re(z)=-r$. Now, if you ask the derivative of $\log(z)$ w.r.t. $z$, you will get
\begin{equation} \frac{\mathrm{d}log(z)}{\mathrm{d}z} = -\frac{\mathrm{d}log(z)}{\mathrm{d}r} = -\frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{z}.\end{equation}
Note that for a complex number, $r>0$.

It is worthwhile to consider for a while the logarithm and exponential in complex plain. As noted above,
\begin{equation} log(z)=log(r)+i\theta, \end{equation}
and trivially,
\begin{equation} exp(z)=exp(r\cos(\theta))e^{ir\sin(\theta)}. \end{equation}
(The later equation stems from the fact that $z=re^{i\theta}=r\cos(\theta)+ir\sin(\theta)$.)

So, what do logarithm and exponential do? In logarithm, the log of absolute value ($r$) becomes the real part and the phase angel $\theta$ becomes the imaginary part. In exponential, the exponential of the real part becomes the absolute value and the imaginary part becomes the phase angel. This is the true meaning of these functions.